# how to remove horizontal line and vertical line from the tiff image without changing image quality in c#

Tags: c#-4.0, bitmap, imagemagick, image-manipulation, imagemagick-convert

How to Remove Lines Appearing[image] on Scanned Documents.

Comment: Have you tried a search of Stackoverflow as this has come up quite a lot? There is this one which may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46861201/removing-horizontal-lines-from-scanned-image You are also expected to at least have tried something first as people are here to help sort your problems and not write your code for you.

Comment: const float limit = 0.60258f;
              Color c = myBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);

              if (c.GetBrightness() >= limit)
                    {
                        myBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, Color.White);
                        //myBitmap.SetResolution(300, 300);
                    }

               myBitmap.Save(@"E:\1.bmp");

Comment: It would help us test ideas if you posted your input image alone.

Comment: if (openFileDialog2.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                myBitmap = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(openFileDialog2.FileName);
            }

Answer (score 0):

You can add horizontal and vertical lines by code below. Here WHITE color will draw line on top of your image, so if you replace this color with your TIFF image background color, it will appear as if there isn't any line

```
string ImageUrl = @"C:\pics\a.tiff";
Image<Bgr, Byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ImageUrl);
Image<Bgr, byte> res = image.Copy();

LineSegment2D[] lines =
    image
    .Convert<Gray, byte>()
    .Canny(16, 16)
    .HoughLinesBinary(1, Math.PI / 16, 1, 10, 1)[0];

    foreach (LineSegment2D line in lines)
    {
        res.Draw(line, new Bgr(System.Drawing.Color.White), 2);
    }

res.Save(ImageUrl);
```